# How lazy are Django QuerySets?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Will the following code Query the database twice? Of course once to begin the for loop, but does it query the database with len()? I ask this because I know the Django count() function queries the database.

```
events = Events.objects.all()   

for event in events:         #First Query
    print(event.name)

length = len(events)         #Second Query?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will hit database only once as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets)

> In a newly created QuerySet, the cache is empty. The first time a
>   QuerySet is evaluated – and, hence, a database query happens – Django
>   saves the query results in the QuerySet’s cache and returns the
>   results that have been explicitly requested (e.g., the next element,
>   if the QuerySet is being iterated over). **Subsequent evaluations of the
>   QuerySet reuse the cached results**.